# Authenticate users against Active Directory?

Tags: users, distributions, authentication-authorization

I've installed a test server with OpenAtrium, because I'm evaluating some intranet solutions for our organization.

I have a must requirement: users should be authenticated against an Active Directory server. I'm trying to follow this tutorial (https://www.codeenigma.com/community/blog/connecting-your-drupal-site-microsoft-active-directory-server), but I'm completely lost.

I've setup other AD connections (like Liferay or a custom-developed intranet web) using only the server IP, an username and a password and the canonical name of the server (dc=organization,dc=local). But there are lots of parameters to config Drupal's LDAP.

What is the **standard** configuration that should go in a configuration to access to a **standard** Active Directory? What should I put in the "LDAP Group Configuration", "LDAP to OG group Configuration" and "LDAP to Drupal role Configuration" groups?

I'm using the latest releases of Drupal, OpenAtrium, and the LDAP components.

Comment: Most of the fields are optional. I'd recommend installing an AD browser and testing your settings there first. That way you can also choose an appropriate base path. Next, you need support in the web server which I found the most trying. Have you done that? Are you serving on Linux? I'd recommend testing that in pure PHP first. Further, is there any such thing as a standard AD configuration? I'll look up my notes and reply back.

Comment: A node at Drupal.org claims to show the solution:  (node 486000)